# SQL Server Group By Combine Pivot Table Approaches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables which designed like survey questions.

Answer table store like below. One answer related with three questions. QuestionId 1 and QuestionId 2 store Yes or No answers. If QuestionId 1 and QuestionId 2 both of them answer Yes, I want QuesiontId 3 to sum count with column value otherwise alias should be Others. Which approach is better , could u please help :)

```
AnswerId | QuestionId | QuestionOptionText
---------+------------+-------------------
   1     |   1        |      No
   1     |   2        |      No
   1     |   3        |      0
 --------------------------------------
   2     |   1        |      Yes
   2     |   2        |      No
   2     |   3        |      0
--------------------------------------
   3     |   1        |      No
   3     |   2        |      Yes
   3     |   3        |      1-10
--------------------------------------
   4     |   1        |      Yes
   4     |   2        |      Yes
   4     |   3        |      1-10
--------------------------------------
   5     |   1        |      Yes
   5     |   2        |      Yes
   5     |   3        |      11-20
```

Result should be like that

```
1-10 | 11-20 | Other
-----+-------+-------
 1   |   1   |   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a self join of the three types of question, and then the summing logic is easier. A different table structure would probably have simplified things. Normally you would have each question in a separate column.

```
select 
sum(iif(ans1 = 'Yes' and ans2 = 'Yes' and ans3 = '1-10',1,0)) as '1-10',
sum(iif(ans1 = 'Yes' and ans2 = 'Yes' and ans3 = '11-20',1,0)) as '11-20',
sum(iif(ans1 <> 'Yes' or ans2 = 'Yes',1,0)) as 'other'
from (
  select QuestionOptionText as ans1 from t where QuestionId = 1
) as a1
inner join (
  select QuestionOptionText as ans2 from t where QuestionId = 2
) as a2
on a1.AnswerId = a2.AnswerId
inner join (
  select QuestionOptionText as ans3 from t where QuestionId = 3
) as a3
on a1.AnswerId = a3.AnswerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(case when QuestionOptionText = '1-10' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when QuestionOptionText = '11-20' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when QuestionOptionText not in ('1-10', '11-20') then 1 else 0 end)
from t
where QuestionId = 3;
```

Comment: Thank your answer but it is not. Maybe i didn't explain very well. Even if Question Id = 3 contains like 1-10,11-20 if the Question Id 1 and Question 2 values are No then it should be marked Others.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two levels of aggregation. First compute the outcome of each series of `answerId`, the pivot the resultset:

```
select 
    sum(case when res =  '1-10' then 1 else 0 end) res_1_10,
    sum(case when res = '11-20' then 1 else 0 end) res_1_20,
    sum(case when res = 'Other' then 1 else 0 end) res_other
from (
    select
        case when max(case when QuestionId in (1, 2) then QuestionOptionText end) = 'Yes'
             then max(case when QuestionId = 3 then QuestionOptionText end)
             else 'Other'
        end res
    from mytable
    group by answerId
) t
```